# Wrong struct returned from separate package function

Tags: go

I develop application on my Ubuntu 18.04 with go.

I have config package. The idea is to use this package in another packages to get configurations. Package config has struct variable `_Config`. The idea that function `GetConfig` will return `_Config`, and when `_Config` not filled the function will firstly fill `_Config` from json file.

The config package looks like this:

```
package config

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/tkanos/gonfig"
)

type Config struct {
    DB struct{
        DBHost string
        DBPort uint
        DBUser string
        DBPassword string
        DBName string
    }
}

var _Config Config

func GetConfig() Config {
    if (Config{}) == _Config {
        _Config := Config{}
        err := gonfig.GetConf("/home/mike/go/src/project/config.json", &_Config)
        if err != nil{
            panic("Error when parsing config")
        }
        fmt.Println(_Config.DB)
    }
    return _Config
}
```

And the result of `Println` is:

```
{127.0.0.1 3306 user Password project}
```

The code of main package looks like:

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "project/config"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mysql"
    _ "project/config"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    _config := config.GetConfig()
    fmt.Println(_config)
}
```

And the result of `Println` is:

```
{{ 0   }}
```

The json file looks like:

```
{
  "DB": {
    "DBHost": "127.0.0.1",
    "DBPort": 3306,
    "DBUser": "user",
    "DBPassword": "Password",
    "DBName": "project"
  }
}
```

So why is that? Why I can't get correct config in main package? The problem I think that I have wrong imagination about how Go works in such situation.

Please clarify this moment for me, and is it good approach for config in application ? If not, what is good pattern? The idea is to have one access and one responsible package for config which I can use everywhere

Comment: drop that line _Config := Config{} . Your problem has _nothing_ to do with configurations and returning structs and packages. (Nitpick. Stop using underscores and blank imports).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a line in `GetConfig()` function -
`_Config := Config{}`.

Here, you are declaring a new variable `_Config` in local scope and shadowing the global variable. Remove this line and try again. Due to shadowing, global variable is not populated with config from json.